# How to get notified when a server started with gcloud is completely up

Tags: kernel, startup, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Is there a way to detect when a server is completely up (i.e. finished all the kernel startup tasks)? This is a Google Compute Engine Instance.

```
Nov 18 10:58:51 image-name google: No startup script found in metadata.
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.491829] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2414]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.703142] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2414]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.735867] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2414]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.771732] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2260]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.797540] device vethfa3ab85 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.804420] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethfa3ab85: link is not ready
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   28.028306] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethfa3ab85: link becomes ready
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   28.035505] docker0: port 1(vethfa3ab85) entered forwarding state
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   28.041963] docker0: port 1(vethfa3ab85) entered forwarding state
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   28.048532] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): docker0: link becomes ready
Nov 18 10:58:54 image-name kernel: [   28.980082] IPv6: eth0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::42:acff:fe11:1 detected!
Nov 18 10:59:08 image-name kernel: [   43.068094] docker0: port 1(vethfa3ab85) entered forwarding state
Nov 18 10:59:53 image-name kernel: [   87.944452] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2864]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:59:53 image-name kernel: [   88.001012] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2864]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:59:53 image-name kernel: [   88.049510] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2815]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
```

My problem is that I can connect to it using SSH when kernel progress is below 30% and some processes are not yet started. I want to detect somehow if the server has completed startup.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own script to call the following command frequently:

```
gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output INSTANCE_NAME
```

The serial port output will provide you with all the logs on your instance including the services that started as well.

Comment: Interesting command. I will try it!